# Hit check runs multiple times

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to apply a simple hit check function into my shooting game written in JavaScript.

Here's the code I put on jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Reverseblade/04whL56j/

To start out, I programmed it to output a console message "Hit!" when one of the enemy's attacks hits the hero (the blue rectangle). However, for some reason, it shows the same console message "Hit!" three times for each collision, and I can't figure out why.

Since I'm in the middle of sprucing it up, please excuse for its unreadability. It's also not opp I assume. (Which is what I've still got to learn about)

The lines where the error is likely to occur is inside the following function:

```
function updateBullets(skill){
  for (var i = 0; i < enemy.bullets[skill].length; i++) {

    ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";

    if(enemy.bullets[skill][i]["moving"] === true && hitTestWithHero(enemy.bullets[skill], i )) {
      enemy.bullets[skill][i]["y"] = 1000;
      enemy.bullets[skill][i]["moving"] = false;
      console.log("hit!");
    }


    if (enemy.bullets[skill][i]["moving"] === false) {
      //          console.log("this bullet is set to false");
      continue;
    }

    ctx.fillRect(enemy.bullets[skill][i]["x"] - enemy.bullets[skill][i]["w"] / 2 , enemy.bullets[skill][i]["y"] - enemy.bullets[skill][i]["h"] / 2, enemy.bullets[skill][i]["w"], enemy.bullets[skill][i]["h"]);
  }
  updatingEnemyBullets = false;
}
```

Any advice will be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: I really recommend you extract `enemy.bullets[skill][i]` into a local. It will improve quality dramatically.

Comment: I think you should put the continue statement after the console.log() statement, not in other if statement.